# Does anybody knows how a query is read by php when I call it?

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony

I'm having a hard time trying to compare dates in php using symfony framework when one of the dates is comming from a sql, I try to compare both dates but the one I'm calling from postgresql just won't be read as a regular date and I can't debug it because for some reason when there's a var_dump(), an echo() or a print_r() on the code it just freezes

I've tried to use it as an array, as string and so on, but I just can't take the response in a way that I'm able to compare with the current date.

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isClientExpired(Clients $client)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $name = $client->getName();
    $query = $em->getConnection()->prepare("

        SELECT MAX(av.expiring_date) 
        FROM ms_evaluations ev, ms_users_roles usr, ms_users us, 
        ms_clients cl
        WHERE us.name = '$name' 
        AND us.id = cl.user_client 
        AND ev.urid_avaliado = usr.id 
        AND usr.user_id = us.id

      ");
    $query->execute();
    $date = $query->fetchAll();
    $today = date('Y/m/d');

    if ($date<$today) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The function should return true if the client evaluation was expired and false if it wasn't, but instead it always returns false. 
The fact that I can't debug the code makes it even harder because I'm unable to see how is that query or the date comming to me and consequently I'm not able to figure out how to treat the response for my code to work. Does anybody at least knows how that date is comming to me? when I execute it directly on postgree it retuns me something like:

|´´´´max´´´´|
|2019/23/08|

It's a single row and a single column response, at least on postgre

Thanks in advance folks

Comment: You're comparing a string `$today = date('Y/m/d');` with (presumably) an array `$date = $query->fetchAll();`. Of course it returns false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `fetchAll()` as the documentation say, is an array:

https://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchall.php

You should get the first result of `fetchAll()` or use `fetchColumn()`.

https://www.php.net/manual/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php